# Nifi: Consume Azure Event Hub with an enterprise proxy environment

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-eventhub

I have a use case in Nifi to consume data from Event Hub. However, the Nifi server is sitting behind a proxy. The proxy also requires username and password for authorization. So far, I have found out `GetAzureEventHub` processor does the job but it lacks full proxy controller service.

I would like to know what could be the best way to deal in such a situation.

Comment: the best solution - to ask net-admins to provide for nifi server direct assess to your  Azure Event Hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways around it. Azure Event Hubs client, by default, is configured to talk to the Service using an open standard called [AMQP](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf).

The `IANA` assigned port for the secure version of `AMQP` protocol a.k.a `AMQPS` is `5671`. So, here goes the first option:

- You will need to work with your admin to allow traffic on port `5671` and to opt out of username-password (aka BASIC) auth for this traffic. This is a complicated option - but, should be technically possible.

Second option & I guess most practical one - in your case:

- configure the Event Hubs library to talk `AMQP` over `WebSockets`. While creating `EventHubClient`, set the `TransportType` property on `ConnectionStringBuilder` to `AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS`. This will allow you to talk on the standard HTTPS port which all proxies are configured to run with - which `WebSockets` uses. If you configure `proxySettings` at java process level, the library already understands it. I tried to document the details instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/releases/tag/1.2.0).

Now, the only limitation you will hit with this approach is that - `apache-nifi` uses and older version of EventHubs client (`0.14.x), whereas, you will need`1.2.0`to be able to use the`WebSockets over proxy`.

There are some breaking changes between these 2 versions -  [that we documented here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/releases/tag/1.0.0) - which should help you with migration. Happy coding!

[more on Event Hubs...](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: Added an corresponding issue in the Nifi Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6240